# How to copy data from one column in certain table to same named column in another table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, copy

I have two SQL Server tables `sub_aminer_author2paper` and `sub_aminer_paper`, and there is a common column `pid`.

Another column `aid` exists in only one table i.e. `sub_aminer_author2paper`.

Now I have to copy column `aid` from table `sub_aminer_author2paper` to newly created column `aid` in the table `sub_aminer_paper`, whereas the column `pid` in table `sub_aminer_paper` should match the `pid` in table `sub_aminer_author2paper`

I have tried this query as:

```
insert into sub_aminer_paper (sub_aminer_paper.aid) 
    (select sub_aminer_author2paper.aid  
     from sub_aminer_author2paper 
     INNER JOIN sub_aminer_paper ON sub_aminer_paper.pid = sub_aminer_author2paper.pid)
```

But it not works as required, it has inserted all the `aid` values at end of the table as

[image: Sql Query Result]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column named aid with null in sub_aminer_paper table. Then simply update it.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.aid = B.aid
FROM sub_aminer_paper A
INNER JOIN sub_aminer_author2paper B ON A.pid = B.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are describing an [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) scenario here, not an [INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), if I understand you correctly.

Update statements can include a from part with multiple tables joined like this:

```
UPDATE sub_aminer_paper 
SET aid = sub_aminer_author2paper.aid
FROM sub_aminer_author2paper 
INNER JOIN sub_aminer_paper ON sub_aminer_paper.pid = sub_aminer_author2paper.pid
```

This statement will update the aid column for existing rows in sub_aminer_paper with the aid value found in sub_aminer_author2paper for matching pid.